# Python Regex to extract codes from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like -

```
Srting = "$33.53 with 2 coupon codes : \r\n\r\n1)  CODEONE\r\n\r\n2)  
CODETWO \r\n\r\nBoth coupons only work if you buy 1 by 1"
```

I want to extract coupon codes "CODEONE" and "CODETWO" from this string if the following if condition gets true -

```
if  "coupon code" in string:
```

Please help how i can extract these coupon codes? Actually i need a generic RE for this because i may have other strings where location of the codes may occur at different place and it is also possible that there is only one code

Comment: Split the string on `\r\n\r\n` and take the 2nd and 3rd elements?

Comment: Actually i need a generic RE for this because i may have other strings where location of the codes may occur at different place and it is also possible that there is only one code

Comment: Have you considered mentioning that important information in your question?

Comment: I updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

```
import re
Srting = "$33.53 with 2 coupon codes : \r\n\r\n1)  CODEONE\r\n\r\n2) CODETWO \r\n\r\nBoth coupons only work if you buy 1 by 1"

for i in re.findall("\d+\)(.*)", Srting):
    print(i.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
CODEONE
CODETWO
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your quick response. here is the output of this re -
['1)  SAVETEN\r', '2)  EXTRA10 \r']